# How can i store the Ant Design's Time Picker time?

Tags: reactjs, antd

This is the time picker:

```
<TimePicker
          defaultValue={moment("12:08", format)}
          format={format}
          placeholder="Horário"
        />
```

I tried something like

```
const [time, setTime] = useState("");
```

And at the time picker

```
onChange={(e) => setTime(e.target.value)}
```

But it just returns an empty string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`onChange` have the following type.

```
onChange?: ((value: moment.Moment | null, dateString: string) => void) | undefined
```

The first parameter have the type Moment & second one is string. You can get the time from the second parameter and store it in state or if you want to customize time before storing it somewhere, you can use moment type value, apply any custom logic. You are trying to get value using `e.target.value`. It's onChange parameter are different as compare to normal field.
Hope this solve your problem

**Complete Code**

```
import moment from 'moment';
import { useState } from 'react';
import { TimePicker } from 'antd';

const format = 'HH:mm';

export default function App() {
    const [time, setTime] = useState('12:08');

    return (
        <TimePicker
            format={format}
            value={moment(time, format)}
            placeholder='Horário'
            // onChange?: ((value: moment.Moment | null, dateString: string) => void) | undefined
            onChange={(value, dateString) => {
                console.log('Time', value, dateString);
                setTime(dateString);
            }}
        />
    );
}
```

Comment: The documentation mentions that time is returned as Dayjs (https://ant.design/components/time-picker#components-time-picker-demo-basic). I couldnt figure out the M output. I guess its moment.Moment. Where did you find this info?

Answer (score 0):

You need dayJs if you want to manipulate time.

```
      onChange={(time, timeString) => {
        console.log(time, timeString);
        let test = dayjs(time);
        console.log("test", test.format());
        // "2022-12-06T03:00:00+05:00"
      }}
```

Install: https://day.js.org/docs/en/installation/node-js